# Finish function higher in hierarchy

Tags: c#

I am tired of writing:

```
if(objectA!=null) 
return;
```

or:

```
if(objectB==null) 
return;
```

So I was hope to shorten this snippet, to something like this:

```
Returns.IfNull(objectA);
```

it is pretty match the same length but usually there are few objects to check and adding `params` as parameter can shorten:

```
if(objectA==null || objectB!=null || objectC!=null) 
return;
```

to:

```
Returns.IfNull(objectA,objectB,objectC);
```

Basically function `IfNull` have to get access to function one step higher in stack trace and finish it. But that's only idea, I don't know if it's even possible. Can I find simililar logic in some lib?

Comment: What you are wanting is essentially an extension method - although slightly different with the `Returns` class ...

Comment: How would your IfNull method know whether to check for is null or is not null like you're prior example?

Comment: @IAbstract: Even then an extension method can't "return" the function above it in the stack

Comment: @James: yeah, that's where we do `MonkeyWrench.Insert()` ...

Comment: @IAbstract: Very true...  those darn monkey wrenches...

Comment: I'm kind of curious what annoys you so much about `if (object1 != null) return;`. It's short, and *really* clear about what it does.

Comment: Why do you have many `if(objectA!=null) return;`?  This is a rather rare pattern in my experience.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I was guessing that was a typo given his sample method usage above and below, but i could be wrong...

Comment: @Jamie Dixon There should be IfNotNull method also

Comment: @dlev Not really annoys, but I think that checking if reference is or isn't null is so common construction that there should be even shorten way to write it

Comment: @CodeInChaos For me it's pretty often, maybe I should try reorganize code to avoid this construction?

Comment: @James I wasn't referring to the typo. I meant the general "return on null" pattern. @ Twelve In my experience most failed null checks either constitute a contract violation, or require special handling. Occasionally "return on null" turns up, but not often enough for it to warrant any complains about verbosity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you are essentially asking the function to exit the function higher than itself which isn't desirable nor really possible unless you throw an exception (which isn't returning per se).

So, you can either do your simple and concise if-null-return checks, or what you may want to do there instead is to throw a well defined exception, but I don't recommend exceptions for flow-control.  If these are exceptional (error) circumstances, though, then consider throwing an ArgumentNullException() and handling it as appropriate.

You could write some helper methods to throw ArgumentNullException() for you, of course, to clean it up a bit:

```
    public static class ArgumentHelper
    {
        public static void VerifyNotNull(object theObject)
        {
            if (theObject == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            }
        }

        public static void VerifyNotNull(params object[] theObjects)
        {
            if (theObjects.Any(o => o == null))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            }
        }
    }
```

Then you could write:

```
public void SomeMethod(object obj1, object obj2, object obj3)
{
    ArgumentHelper.VerifyNotNull(obj1, obj2, obj3);

    // if we get here we are good!
}
```

But once again, this is exceptions and not a "return" of the previous method in the stack, which isn't directly possible.

Comment: The caller can still catch the exception and stubborningly refuse to return early, however.

Comment: Very true :-) but it is the only way to tell the method above it potentially to exit (if unhandled)...

Comment: @Jamie, I was thinking about `longjmp()` myself, but I guess it's harder to design a safe, managed language when you have to support nonlocal jumps ;)

Comment: This reminds me of [code contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992) where you can do `Contract.Requires( obj1 != null ... )`.

Comment: @Frederic, Jamie Your comment reminds me of Symbian exception system, goto is wrong in every form :)

Comment: Thanks for answer James, it won't solve all my issues but your ArgumentHelper is really nice idea!

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for something that only the language designer can fix for you. 
I have proposed one thing by [myself](http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2009/11/22/136473.aspx).
The .? operator does return from the current method with the default return value when the argument left to it is null.

```
return appSettings.?GetElementKey(key).?Value ?? "";
```

Perhaps we will see it some day in C# 6?

Comment: I hope myself for something like that

Answer (score 1):

To do similar comparison checks I once defined the following extension method:

```
/// <summary>
///   Returns whether the object equals any of the given values.
/// </summary>
/// <param name = "source">The source for this extension method.</param>
/// <param name = "toCompare">The objects to compare with.</param>
/// <returns>
///   True when the object equals any of the passed objects, false otherwise.
/// </returns>
public static bool EqualsAny( this object source, params object[] toCompare )
{
    return toCompare.Any( o => o.Equals( source ) );
}
```

It can simplify redundant checks, e.g.:

```
string someString = "bleh";
bool anyEquals = someString.EqualsAny( "bleh", "bloeh" );
```

In your case where you check for multiple null checks you could use it as follows:

```
if ( EqualsAny( null, objectA, objectB, objectX ) ) return;
```

---

On another note, your code reminds me of [Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992) which allows you to define pre and post conditions. In case this is your scenario - perhaps not as I don't see why you call `return` - it might interest you. Part of it is available for free in .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can not invoke another method and expect it to return to the callee of the current method (you could if we had something like continuation passing style; alas, we do not).

You could say:

```
if(new[] { objectA, objectB, objectC }.Any(x => x != null)) {
    return;
}
```

Or:

```
if(new[] { objectA, objectB, objectC }.AnyAreNotNull()) {
    return;
}
```

Here, `AnyAreNotNull` is:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions {
    public static bool AnyAreNotNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) {
        Contract.Requires(source != null);
        return source.Any(x => x != null);
    }
}
```

But really, there is nothing wrong with just writing the usual code for this situation.

Comment: That's just as ugly, and I would argue, much more confusing than just doing the basic check he was doing above. :)

Comment: Yes, in this case I'd argue less is more...  Creating a colleciton just to see if any were null seems a bit excessive.  Personally I like checking them and then throwing ArgumentNullException, but that's providing he's fine with exceptions...

Answer (score 0):

No, a method can't return the method above it.

Best you could do is create a method that returned true if any of its params were null, then do `if (ReturnHelper.AllNull(obj1, obj2, obj3)) return;` but i'd say this is much less readable.